# Minimise / maximise a div

Tags: php, javascript, html, minimize, maximize

I ve created a chat appliction in one DIV.
Now i need it to be placed in the bottom of page, which should be minimised & maximized
Can any one help me

```
<div  style="height:40px;  width:300px;  background-color:#CC66FF; position:absolute;bottom:15px;"  >

<div id="vithu" style="height:40px;  width:200px;"></div>
<span id="error_msg"></span>
<table>
<form method="post">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="txt_msg_box" id="txt_msg_box" ></td>
<td><input type="button"  value="Chat" onClick="save_chat();"  /></td>
</tr>  
<input type="hidden" id="hdn_username" name="hdn_username" value="<?php echo  rand_str();?>" />
</form>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by minimized/maximized. The browser window? What is the bottom of the page: The bottom of the browser window, or of the document?

Comment: my div content should be minimised and maximised,in the bottom of the window

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for something like [this](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/samples.html)... modal windows using prototype

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery to set the display property of the div to none. Add "divNotDisplayed" class when you hide the div. If this class is present then alter the size of other divs. Add "divDisplayed" class when you display the div and once again alter other divs.

Udachi

Comment: Also get used to keeping styling in CSS and js in a seperate file.